# How do I add a custom condition in ng-if?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a pre-evaluated conditional statement to be used inside my ng-if. Something like this, in my angular code:

```
scope.condition = "item.chosen == true";         ---(1)
```

I need to use this condition in my ng-if condition, something like this:

```
<div ng-if="{{condition}}"></div>                ---(2)
```

Which would ideally be evaluated as

```
<div ng-if="item.chosen == true"></div>          ---(3)
```

This of course doesn't work. Just to clarify, I cannot directly use the code in 3 because as I mentioned the scope.condition variable is pre-evaluated and I can't be sure what the string value might be, except that it will be a valid conditional statement.

How do I achieve this?

EDIT 1:

Further clarification, the condition variable need not necessarily be **item.chosen == true**. It could also be something like **item.count > limit** or **item.available == false**. Basically there is no way to know for sure what the condition will be, just that it will always be a valid conditional statement in string format.

Comment: If `item.chosen` is a string value, you can do something like this: `<div ng-if="item.chosen === 'compareString'></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this

```
<div ng-if="$eval(condition)"></div>
```

or

```
//view
<div ng-if="condition"></div>

//controller
$scope.item.chosen = false;
$scope.condition = $scope.$eval('item.chose == true')
```

Comment: This worked best for me! Can't believe I didn't know about $eval. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to store it like

```
scope.condition = item.chosen;
```

and then use it like

```
<div ng-if="condition"></div>
```

it will be evaluated like

```
<div ng-if="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do,

```
<div ng-if="condition"></div>
```

Comment: This will not work. As hadi said scope.condition = "item.chosen == falsse" will also be a true condition

Comment: then `ng-if` always is true.

Comment: @Hadi yes. It will always be true.